# Self-adjoint on dot product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let be $V = M_3(\mathbb{R})$ the vector space of the real antisymmetric matrix and let be $\phi$ the scalar product defined by $\phi(X,Y) = tr(^tXY)~ \forall X, Y \in V$. Let be $A$ a symmetric matrix.

a) Prove that $AXA \in V$ for each $X \in V$

b) Let be $f:V\rightarrow V$ the linear application defined by $f(X) = AXA$ for each $X \in V$. Prove that $f$ is self-adjoint for $\phi$.

c) Let be:

$
A = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 2 & 0 \\ 2 & -3 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}
$

find an orthonormal basis of $V$ for $\phi$ and of eigenvectors for $f$.

**My try:**

a) Easy to see that $^t(AXA) =$ $^tA^tX^tA = -AXA$

b) We want to prove that $\phi (f(X), Y)=\phi(AXA,Y)=\phi(X,AYA)=\phi(X,f(Y))$. <strike>I tried in several ways but none solved my point. How to go ahead?</strike> **Solved!**

c) Let be $X$ a generic antisymmetric matrix:

$
X = \begin{bmatrix}0 & a & b \\ -a & 0 & c \\ -b & -c & 0 \end{bmatrix}
$

Now $f(X) = \begin{bmatrix}0 & -4a & 2c \\ 4a & 0& (2b-3c) \\ -2c & -(2b-3c) & 0 \end{bmatrix}$

Maybe I can find the eigenvectors of $f(X)$ and after orthonormalize them with gram-schmidt process?

Comment: you are already there, dont forget $X,Y$ are skew-symmetric matrices. Make use of the fact $tr(MN)=tr(NM)$. This in fact is the killing form of $SO(3)$.

Comment: @TroyWoo but I have $tr(^t(AXA)Y)=tr(^tXAYA)$ that I can manage to obtain $tr(AXAY) = tr(^t(AX)^t(AY))$. Maybe I've done saying that $AX = AY = 0$?

Comment: $(AXA)^TY=-A(XAY)$, $X^TAYA=-(XAY)A$.

Comment: @TroyWoo Thanks… sometimes we don't see the simplest things.

Comment: @TroyWoo I added the last point of the problem with my idea of solution… have it sense or not?

Comment: I went out shopping, and now you don't need my answer. I think it is polite to approve the gentlman's solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{eqnarray}
\langle Y, f(X)  \rangle &=&  \operatorname{tr} (Y^T AXA) \\
&=&  \operatorname{tr} (AY^T AX) \\
&=&  \operatorname{tr} (XAY^T A) \\
&=&  \operatorname{tr} (X (AY^T A)) \\
&=&  \operatorname{tr} ((AY^T A) X) \\
&=& \operatorname{tr} ((AY A)^T X) \\
&=&  \langle f(Y), X  \rangle \\
&=&  \langle f^*(Y), X  \rangle
\end{eqnarray}

Let $B_1 = {1 \over \sqrt{2}}(E_{12}-E_{21})$, $B_2 = {1 \over \sqrt{2}}( E_{13}-E_{31})$, $B_3 = {1 \over \sqrt{2}}( E_{23}-E_{32})$.
It is easy to see that $B_k$ form an orthonormal basis for $V$.

Furthermore, $f(B_1) = -4 B_1$, $f(B_2) = 2 B_3$ and $f(B_3) = 2B_2-3 B_3$.

In the basis $B_k$, $f$ has the matrix $\begin{bmatrix} -4 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 2 \\
0 & 2 & -3 \end{bmatrix}$, which has eigenvalues $-4,-4, 1$.

**Addendum**:
Here is a different approach:

Note that $V^\bot$ is the space of symmetric matrices (use the basis $B_k$ above to see this), and define $f$ on the space of all $3 \times 3$ matrices as $f(X) = AXA$.

Since $A$ is symmetric, it has a basis of eigenvectors $u_1,u_2,u_3$ wth corresponding eigenvalues $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \lambda_3$ (which we can find are $-4,1,1$ using the standard basis).

Note that $f(u_i u_j^T) = \lambda_i \lambda_j u_i u_j^T$, and that the $u_i u_j^T$ form a basis for the space of all $3 \times 3$ matrices. Furthermore, $f(V) \subset V$ (and $f(V^\bot) \subset V^\bot$, not that it matters here),
so if we can find a basis for $V$ in terms of $u_k$, then we are finished.

Indeed, if we let $\beta_{ij} = u_i u_j^T-u_j u_i^T$, with $i<j$, a little work shows that $\beta_{ij} \in V$ and since there are three of them, we have 
$V=\operatorname{sp} \{ \beta_{ij} \}_{i<j}$. Since $f(\beta_{ij}) = \lambda_i \lambda_j \beta_{ij}$, we see that the eigenvalues of $f$ restricted to $V$ are $\lambda_i \lambda_j$ with $i < j$. Hence the eigenvalues are $-4, -4, 1$.

A little more work shows that the $\beta_{ij}$ are orthogonal, hence they can be made into an orthonormal set. A quick computation shows that $\|\beta_{ij}\|^2 = \langle \beta_{ij} , \beta_{ij} \rangle  = 2$, so the
required set of eigenvectors is ${1 \over \sqrt{2}} (u_i u_j^T-u_j u_i^T)$, with $i<j$.

Comment: Did you find it at a glance?

Comment: Well, the basis for $V$ is just by inspection, the elements of the basis must be skew-symmetric, and there are three of them. Then I just computed $f(B_k)$ by multiplying the matrices. One eigenvalue of $f$ is immediate, the other two come from the eigenvalues of a $2 \times 2$ matrix.

Comment: There may be a simpler way, I just don't see one right now...

Comment: I'll study your solution, really thanks!

Comment: I made a mistake in my computation.

Comment: Me too when I wrote the $f(X)$. In any case don't should be $f(B_2) = 2B_2$? And the eigenvalues of the new matrix so -4, 2, -3 (can't be that if $B_1$ and $B_2$ are already eigenvector)

Comment: I believe the above is correct. The eigenvalues of $f$ must be a subset of the products of pairs of eigenvalues of $A$. I will add another approach above shortly.

Comment: Elegant solution, thanks again!